# How do I fix the automounting of USB drives after installing Openbox on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: udev, openbox, policykit, exfat, udisks

I am installing Openbox on Ubuntu 16.04 because I need to eliminate the top window bar for the application I am running.  This appears to be a good solution except that the system no longer automounts USB drives.   The process udisksd should be mounting the USB drives.   I can logout from Openbox and login with the Unity window manager and the system will again automount USB drives.  Whenever I login with Openbox the system will not automount USB drives. 
I have a udev rule that executes when it recognizes that the USB drive has been plugged in.  I tried adding commands to the rule to mount the drive.  But they do not work.  The commands I have tried are basically:

1. udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdb1
2. udevil mount /dev/sdb1

These commands work from the command line but not from the udev rule.

I have also tried having the rule execute a program that executes the commands after a delay from a thread.  In case it makes any difference, the USB drive is formatted with the exfat filesystem.

For the first command I get the error:
"Error looking up object for device /dev/sdb1"

After the second command when I try to access the drive I get:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ ls -aFtlr /media
    ls: cannot access '/media/58000115': Transport endpoint is not connected
    total 16
    d??????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? 58000115/
    drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4096 Apr 13 13:28 ../
    drwxr-x---+  2 root root 4096 Apr 20 14:59 root/
    drwxr-x---+  3 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:57 ubuntu/
    drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:57 ./
```

Comment: pcmanfm should work with gvfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy solution that worked for me.:
  https://github.com/six-k/automount-usb

I spent a long time trying alternatives.